# What is "&H5DC"?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My friend had a VB.NET project and lost the source. I decompiled project binaries and got it back. In the decompiled codes I saw some lines like `image.Height = &H5DC`. Apparently it is integer but I don't get it, what is "&H5DC"? Is it hexadecimal? How can I find out its actual integer value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hexadecimal.

You can configure Reflector to always use decimal in Options.

You can convert it to decimal using [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x5DC+in+Decimal) or Windows calculator.  (`&H` is a VB.Net prefix and is not part of the number)

Explanation: Compiled IL does not distinguish between decimal literals and hexadecimal literals.  (They're both numbers).  Reflector tries to guess which numbers were probably hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

&H5DC = 1500 as 'normal' (decimal) value